# How can Multipeer Connectivity Framework (iOS7) be used, when there is no Wi-Fi router nearby and also the bluetooth interface is turned off?

Tags: ios, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I just discovered that 2 (or more) peers can connect to each other (and also send data) without being connected to a router nor having bluetooth turned on.

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) I can read out that additionally to Bluetooth PAN and infrastructure Wi-Fi also peer-to-peer Wi-Fi is supported - is this the reason why it is still working or is the framework still secretly using Bluetooth?

(PS! The devices, which I am using do not have a cellular chipset implemented)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, modern iOS and OS X devices can talk to each other using wifi without being connected to a router.

It's used for all kinds of things.

Comment: Based on the speed tests, I assume that it is not Wi-Fi Direct (up to 54 Mbs) but rather AdHoc based Wi-Fi (up to 11 MBs, although transferring a video of 5 MB took about 2-3 minutes), correct?

Comment: @iosappdeveloper87 I have no idea what it is precisely, I wouldn't assume it's anything standard like Wi-Fi Direct and AdHoc Wi-Fi. Note that macs can talk to other macs and iOS devices can talk to iOS devices, but you can't connect a mac and an iOS device to each other directly right now. There must be some reason for that, probably because it uses a different protocol. On my mac I often copy large/multi gigabyte files and it runs plenty fast enough.